# Voltera integral equation of first kind.

Tags: integral-equations

The curve $y=y(x)$ passing  through the point $(\sqrt{3},1)$ and defined by the following property $$\int_{0}^{y}\frac{f(v)dv}{\sqrt{y-v}}=4\sqrt{y}$$ where $f(y)=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y^{'2}}}$ is a part of a

$1.$ Straight line.

$2.$ Circle.

$3.$ Parabola.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please give me some hint or solution of the problem. Answer is given $1$st option. Thank a lot.

Comment: I don't understand what $f(y)=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y^{'2}}}$ is there for ? In particular the presence of a derivative $y'$...

Comment: its derivative square.....

Comment: All right, the square of a derivative. But here is not the problem. The problem is that if you write $f(y)$, $y$ is a variable, so what do you mean if you express it by $f(y)=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y^{'2}}}$ ? Do you understand what I mean ? And what is the connection with your integral ?

Comment: Indeed, because of the derivative, the integral on the LHS makes no sense when one injects the expression of $f$ in it (and I find highly annoying that you chose to ignore @JeanMarie's point) . What is the source of this problem?

Comment: It appears, from the accepted answer below, that $f$ is an operator, taking in a differentiable function $y$ and returning a function defined by $x\mapsto \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y'(x)^2}}$. Can you confirm whether this is the case, for the sake of future readers of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considered Volterra equation can be written as an equation for convolution
$$f(y)*\dfrac1{\sqrt y} = 4\sqrt y,$$
or
$$\mathcal L\left\{f(y\right)\}(s)\mathcal L\left\{y^{-1/2}\right\}(s)=4\mathcal L\left\{y^{1/2}\right\}(s),$$
where $\mathcal L(s)$ is [Laplace transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html).
Using the formula
$$\mathcal L\{t^a\}(s) = \dfrac{\Gamma(a+1)}{s^{a+1}}\text{ for }a=-\dfrac12\text{ and }a=\dfrac12$$ 
and taking in attention that $$\Gamma\left(\dfrac12\right)=\sqrt\pi,\quad \Gamma\left(\dfrac32\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2,$$
we have
$$\mathcal L\left\{y^{-1/2}\right\}(s)=\sqrt{\pi}s^{-1/2},$$
$$\mathcal L\left\{y^{1/2}\right\}(s)=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}2s^{-3/2}.$$
Therefore,
$$\mathcal L\left\{f(y\right)\}(s)=\dfrac2s,$$
$$f(y)=2.$$

So
$$\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{y'^2}}=2,$$
$$y'(x)=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt3},$$
$$y(x)=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt3}x,$$
and taking in attention the point $(\sqrt3,1),$
$$y(x)=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}x.$$

So the right answer is $1$ - **"straight line"**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice solution....

Comment: @neelkanth You are welcome!